# wordpress change category presentation after choosing from category dropdown

Tags: javascript, wordpress, post, categories, archive

i am trying to build a plugin that will show a post archive. i did it and it works fine, but i want to add a category dropdown that after choosing one the archive will refresh and will show the choosen category. this is the relevant code, but it's not working. after choosing a category nothing happen, it needs to be refreshed.. any ideas on how to do this?

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select category'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
    function onCatChange() {
        if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
            location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        }
    }
--></script>
</li>
      <ul class="zeevul">
<?php query_posts( array ( 'cat' => 'dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value', 'posts_per_page' => 999));
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  // do whatever you want
?>
<li>
<h2 href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<p><?php echo excerpt($words); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach is wrong here. The combination of Javascript and PHP here is not bi-directional as it displayed.

as far as I know, on the **query_posts** you can't pass parameter from JS to PHP. Right now you are passing a string to query the database with "dropdown.options...." and that is just a string for the server, not a real value.

I think it would be better to make the dropbox a form that post itself with each change. The parameter sent as a post would be the value of the selected index, which is the category ID. "Catch" that value with PHP and simply query the posts of this category.

You can either use "post" or "get", since I think post is a bit trickier to handle in WP.

Hope that helps.